# Convert XHTML to HTML in Ruby

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, xhtml, libxml2

I have a Ruby on Rails application that use the LibXML (libxml-ruby). The site is in HTML. Unfortunately the LibXML outputs XHTML. It doesn't look like a problem at first but there are few corner cases:

```
  input   |       XHTML       |   HTML
----------+-------------------+---------
<strong/> | <strong></strong> | <strong>
  <br/>   |    <br></br>      |   <br>
```

**The question:** Is there a easy way to convert XHTML to HTML?

P.S.
For time being i use these instructions:

```
ret.gsub! /\<(br|hr|img)(\s[^\/\>]*)?\/\>/, '<\1\2>'
ret.gsub! /\<(\w+)(\s[^\/\>]*)?\/>/, '<\1\2></\1>'
```

Comment: Which bindings do you use exactly? Nokogiri? libxml-ruby?

Comment: The project use libxml-ruby. I've edited question.